# Title: Propagating Exceptions from Axon Saga to Spring Boot REST Controller

Tags: spring-boot, rest, exception, axon, saga

I am working on a project utilizing the Axon Framework along with Spring Boot to implement CQRS and Event Sourcing patterns. Within this project, I have defined a Saga to handle a specific business process. In this Saga, I throw a custom InvalidOrderException when certain conditions are not met. Here's a simplified version of my Saga:

```
@Slf4j
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OrderSaga {
    // ...
    @StartSaga
    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "orderId")
    @EventHandler
    public void handle(OrderCreatedEvent orderCreatedEvent) {
        // ...
        try {
            commandGateway.sendAndWait(reserveProductCommand);
        } catch (CommandExecutionException ex) {
            rollbackReservations();
            throw new InvalidOrderException("The product ID: " + productId + " provided in the order is invalid ");
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

I want to handle this InvalidOrderException in my REST controller from where the command initiating this Saga is sent, to inform the user that something went wrong. Here's the relevant part of my REST controller:

```
public class OrderController {
    // ...
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<ReadOrderDto> createOrder(@RequestBody CreateOrderDto createOrderDto){
        CreateOrderCommand createOrderCommand = new CreateOrderCommand(
            // ...
        );

        commandGateway.sendAndWait(createOrderCommand);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(
            createOrderCommand.toToReadProductDto(), HttpStatus.OK
        );
    }
    // ...
}
```

To handle the InvalidOrderException, I tried to create a GlobalExceptionHandler class annotated with @RestControllerAdvice, like so:

```
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidOrderException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleProductServiceException(InvalidOrderException exception) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exception.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

However, this GlobalExceptionHandler does not catch the exception thrown from the Saga. I am looking for a way to propagate this exception back to the REST controller to send a meaningful error response to the client.

I also used the @ExceptionHandler annotation of Axon but this will only work if the exception is thrown in the same class, so this did not help.

Is there a recommended way to handle such exceptions thrown from an Axon Saga in a Spring Boot REST controller, especially to capture and respond to these exceptions where the command was initially sent?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure returning something from the Saga to the rest controller is the right approach. As a Saga is used for a potentially long async running process, from the initial rest call I would just expect a failure, or an Ok, order started kind of return.

From the Saga you could send the appropriate commands or events, so that a projection can be created from which the status can be retrieved. So for example, you could start a subscription query on the order, to provide feedback in an ui.

Comment: Thank you for your response, since i am sending the command in a post route from the controller, how is it possible to start a  subscription query on the order and use its info in the post post route? I was a little bit confused how could i do this but i tryed a little bit different approachm wich is publishing an event from the saga and handle it elsewhere int he order-service to throw an exception there and handle it from the controller, but the event was not getting handled.

Comment: Not in the post route, it can be a call from the client when the command went fine. For the subscription you can either use a websocket or server sent events. The likely problem was that the event you created wasn't a domain event, which it shouldn't be. The event should be handled by an event processor, which is part of the projection, which can be queried. It's not meant to go to the controller directly.

Comment: Maybe an [example](https://github.com/gklijs/bank-axon-graphql/blob/64b1a046f6c1a7bd7e6d3f1eda3c3ada608e024a/graphql-endpoint/src/main/java/tech/gklijs/graphql_endpoint/service/MoneyTransferService.java#L35) works better. In this case the command is send, and immediately a subscription query started. Where a successful response is then mapped to be returned. But you could also do that in two seperate steps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it solve it using a subscriptionQuery, is there a similar way to handle queries, let us say when the client want to fetch an order that does not exist?

Comment: If the order doesn't exist, you can directly return the error from the query?

Comment: No i mean sothing like this:     private ReadUserDto fetchUserInfos(String userId) {
        FetchUserQuery fetchUserQuery = new FetchUserQuery(userId);

        return queryGateway.query(
                    fetchUserQuery,
                    ResponseTypes.instanceOf(ReadUserDto.class)
            ).join();
    }

Comment: So, what would you want to return in that case?

Comment: i got it this is how it worked:     protected Optional<ReadUserDto> fetchUserInformation(String userId) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(
                queryGateway.query(
                                new FetchUserQuery(userId),
                                ResponseTypes.instanceOf(ReadUserDto.class)
                        ).exceptionally(ex -> null)
                        .join()
        );
    } thnak you for your help.